# Best way to retrieve another program's output

Tags: windows, perl, output

it seems I am having issues retrieving the output of another application that I have executed within my perl script.

I've tried to use

```
# Option 1:
open( FH, "program -paramaeters |" ) or warn("$!");
while ( my $line = <FH> ) { print $line }

# Option 2: IPC::Run3's
run3( \@cmd, \undef, \$output );

# Option 3:
my $output = system("program");

# Option 4:
my $output = `program`;

# Option 5:
my $output = exec("program");
```

and none of the above seem to capture the exact string output of the program in question.

I was just wondering if there was a better method than what I have previously listed.

EDIT:

This is for a Windows system

Comment: Make sure that your program doesn't output to standard error.

Comment: Use backticks or `qx()` to capture output from standard output. `system` only gives you the exit status of the program, and `exec` ends your Perl program and cannot return anything at all. If you get no capture from backticks, it is because none was sent.

Answer (score 2):

Use option 1, but add `2>&1` into it like this:

```
open( FH, "program -paramaeters 2>&1 |" ) or warn("$!");
while ( my $line = <FH> ) { print $line }
```

That will capture the stderr output of the program as will as the stdout.

Comment: I should add this is for a Windows system. Does this make any difference?

Comment: It seems like it should work according to this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110930

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions based on your own options.

1: (courtesy of Alcanzar, improved to use lexical vars)  Will retrieve STDOUT & STDERR merged together, reading line-by-line.

```
open( my $FH, "program -paramaeters 2>&1 |" ) or warn("$!");
while ( my $line = <$FH> ) { print $line }
```

2a: retrieve STDOUT & STDERR as independent strings.

```
run3( \@cmd, \undef, \$output, \$error );
```

2b: retrieve STDOUT & STDERR as independent streams via IO::Pipe objects to be read later, perhaps line-by-line.

```
run3( \@cmd, \undef, $output, $error );
```

3: `system()` returns exit code, not output.  *Not what you want*

4: much like option #1.  Output is merged into a single string.

```
my $output = `program 2>&1`;
```

5: `exec()`:  terminate this program and run the specified program.  Exit status will be returned to this program's parent...  *Not what you want*

---

If the child program is long running, or it's output is very large, you may want to avoid using solution #4 (backticks) or replace the scalar references in solution #2 (IPC::Run3) with `IO::Pipe` objects.